# IValidatableObject Validate() for different scenarios

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I’ve been implementing **IValidatableObject** on Model entities, and using **Validate(ValidationContext)** to perform validation, often complex.

Can I use **ValidationContext** to distinguish different validation scenerios?

e.g. take for example a User model where I have 3 validation scenerios:

- Sign up – I want to test an email is unique, and a small selection of required fields have been entered
- Change details – Different email uniqueness check, bit more required details after sign up, not changing password here so it doesn't need checked
- Change password – Only password field to validate

Is this a proper use for it, and if so *how* do I ensure the correct ValidationContext properties are set after a post and before Validate() is called? Or should I be taking a totally different approach?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use ValidationContext?

Comment: I was really asking if it could be used for that. But if it's bad practice or really not intended for identifying "validation groups", then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

For my two cents worth I would say that your model is either in a valid state (applying all validation criteria) or it isn't.  If, under certain circumstances, you don't want to apply a validation then I think you should really be using a separate model (ViewModel, actually).

In your example, I would create a `RegisterViewModel` for sign up and a separate `EditUserViewModel`  for changing details.  Each of these would then have their own validation and they would have a [single responsibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546578.aspx#id0390008).

Creating a fat model that you reuse in many different views is, imho, a bit of a code smell.  I have a number of reasons for thinking this.  Firstly, let's say that you have a single model that is used for all interaction with user data.  It looks like this:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }
}
```

Later you decide to track the browser that was used during registration with the site.  Where do you add that?  It really has nothing to do with the user, so it shouldn't go on the `UserModel` model.  If you had a separate `RegisterViewModel` you could modify it as needed when your registration process changes without concern as to how it would affect the other places it is used.

A more serious problem arises if, for example, you were using the above model with MVC's DefaultModelBinder.  As described [here](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2012/03/11/what-aspnet-mvc-developers-can-learn-from-githubrsquos-security-woes), the user could create their own request and grant themselves administrator privileges even if you don't have the `IsAdministrator` field on the form (by exploiting a mass-assignment vulnerability).  Again, if a separate ViewModel was used without the `IsAdministrator` property it would reduce the surface area for security holes.

The above is just an example, but I'm sure you get the point.

Comment: I take your point, but I'm not hugely keen on duplicating Models with the same or similar properties for different validation scenarios, then reconciling each back to a single database object. It introduces more work and decentralised code.

Answer (score 1):

The `IValidatableObject` is used to perform multiple validations against a single model. In your case you have a `User` model and you want to do three validations and you can do that perfectly by implementing the `IValidatableObject` in the `User` model.

The `ValidationContext` is not bringing much benefit (other than providing access to the context) since we can access all the properties directly in the `Validate` method.

An example of performing multiple validations related to the single model by `IValidatableObject`. (So what is the use of `ValidationContext` here?)

```
public class Party : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Start date is required")]
    [FutureDateValidator(ErrorMessage = "Start date should be a future date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Duration is required")]    
    public int DurationInHours { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No. of joinees is required")]
    [Range(2, 10, ErrorMessage = "No. of joinees should be minimum 2 and not more than 10")]
    public int NoOfJoinees { get; set; }    

    public bool Drinks { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (StartDate.TimeOfDay > new TimeSpan(22 - DurationInHours, 0, 0))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("The party should not exceed after 10.00 PM");
        }

        if (NoOfJoinees < 5 && Drinks)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Drinks are only allowed if no. of joinees is 5 or more.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I'm probably trying to use ValidationContext for something it isn't designed to do, but how would you handle the 3 scenarios in Validate()? Would you add a property/hidden field that maintained the current "action" (Signup, Edit, ChangePass) that could be referenced in Validate(), or do it in the page controller afterwards? I would like to carry out all validation in Validate().